# Excel Add-In Office-JS is asking about Certificate Revocation List

Tags: excel, ssl, office-js

I'm trying to get my Add-In distributed via Office 365 Admin Center. It's been a real pain as they force SSL upon me even though the Add-In works fine via HTTP currently.

The reason I use HTTP is that my Add-In prompts each start that there is no "CRL List" for the SSL Cert of internal API.

[image]

I found how to disable this check, but it appears to be system wide.

**Is there a reason that it works fine in the browser, but prompts in Excel Add-In?**

**Is there a way to disable just for Excel vs system wide?**

This will likely be a separate post, but is there **a way to disable for just one certificate vs system wide?**

Disabling system wide may work, but it's clearly not the correct approach. I'm aware the best approach would be to resolve/setup the CRL, but that is a tall ask just for "my add-in". If I could at least pitch disabling check on a lower/smaller level, it might be accepted.

I haven't tested running in Web just yet to see if I get the SSL prompt in the browser, this is currently on Desktop which is my main target audience.

Update: I've reaserched more and noticed that the internal API uses LDAP for the CRL List. This appears to be working via the browser, but the Excel Add-In isn't passing my Credentials is my guess. I'm not sure how to configure this step at all.

Update: This issue is inconsistent which makes it even harder to diagnose. One possible fix was simply runnung "certutil" to query the list seemed to fix, but as the issue is inconsistent, its hard to say without further testing. I have setup on other terminals and not had the prompt. Then I rebooted after Windows Update and had the prompt, then ran CertUtil and then prompt went away. Other users just never have gotten the prompt.

Comment: https://scotthelme.co.uk/revocation-is-broken/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162091/excel-office-add-in-cant-check-certificate-revocat